# Change content-type on $http.delete in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

In my Angular app, I am sending a config object with an $http.delete request using the following method:

```
return $http.delete('projects/' + projectID + '/activityTypes', {data: [{id: 2}]})
```

This appends the value of my `data` key to the body of the request as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

However, Angular seems to be setting the content-type as `text/plain` by default, and I need to be JSON.

How can I change the content type of this $`http.delete` request?

**EDIT:** I posted a screenshot with the wrong Network tab open (Response Headers instead of Request Headers) by mistake. Here is the correct version:

[image]

@charlietfl, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: image only shows the response headers, not the request headers. Server is the one setting to text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out you can pass multiple options (such as `Content-Type`) within the config object that I was already passing, like so:

```
$http.delete('projects/' + id + '/activityTypes',
    {data: activitiesToDelete, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}});
```

The above is working exactly as intended, so it is indeed possible to send a body with an `$http.delete` using Angular, and further customize the http request using that same config object.

From Angular's [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> - data – {string|Object} – Data to be sent as the request message data.
> - headers – {Object} – Map of strings or functions which return strings    representing HTTP headers to send to the server. If the
>     return value    of a function is null, the header will not be sent.
>     Functions accept    a config object as an argument.